# Why code stops working after this function?

Tags: php

I have some other functions and a html page call after this simple function, but they dont run after this.

```
function page($name){
  $content =<<<eol
<?php
PAGE CONTENT
?>
 eol;
$file = "./search/$name.php";
$open = fopen($file, "w");
fwrite($open, $content);
fclose($open);
    }
```

function works itself, but causes exiting code.

Comment: compelety removed php part , still same problem occurs..

Comment: can you post complete page code ?

Comment: i dont think can do it, but i test a "echo 'etc';" after and before this and phpstorm says "unreachable statment" after function.

Comment: Interesting, at least post some more code.

Comment: PHPSTORM is not good enough in recognizing this syntax, please check in browser.

Comment: ok, i called function with "return" , changed it to "echo" and now it works..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function page($name){
    $content = '<?php PAGE CONTENT ?>';

    $file = "./search/$name.php";
    $open = fopen($file, "w");
    fwrite($open, $content);
    fclose($open);
}

page('file1.txt');
?>
```

Just see if that works, It could be something to do with your HEREDOC syntax (maybe the space before the eol;).

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Chief17
The only right thing is writing to file.

This code

```
<?php
PAGE CONTENT
?>
```

what supposed to do?

Did you mix up   ???
may be it should be like this

```
?>
PAGE CONTENT
<?php
```

**editing after your edit**

You break the php like this why you need this anyway?

Comment: I think he is trying to write a PHP file, that's why he needs the `<?php` `?>` tags, its not clear though, so either of us could be right.

Comment: i only need a new page with certain content, but its not problem, i even deleted entire <?php ?> part and problem still exist.

Comment: I think Chief17 post is fine now I have used it like this before. You must have an error somewhere else on the file.